# Python CSV list manipulation / Date and Time

Tags: python, csv, date, datetime

I am working on a python program that changes the format of an existing CSV

This is the Goal format for the CSV

[image: Goal]

This is the Original State

[image]

3 obstacles

1. remove "-" from modelchass **(Complete)**
2. add "-" to prod date and also 'T' **(complete)**
3. change PL Seq list to time's / or possibly create new column with times

   Condition, start at 08:00:00

   Condition, each line increase by 1

   Condition, restart for each date

[image]

Condition, restart for H seq

[image]

Steps 1 and 2 I have figured out, but I am lost on step 3;

this is my code so far

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("AMS truck schedule.txt",delimiter=';')
df.to_csv('Demo1.csv')

import csv



with open('Demo1.csv','r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    order_numbers = []
    csvtimes = []
    sequence = []
    for line in csv_reader:
        order_numbers.append(line['MODELCHASS'])
        csvtimes.append(line['Prod Date'])
        sequence.append(line['PL Seq'])

#replace the dash for the order numbers
on = [sub.replace("-","") for sub in order_numbers]
print(on[1225])

newtimes = [x[0] + x[1] +x[2] +x[3] +"-" +x[4] +x[5] +"-" +x[6] +x[7] + "T" for x in csvtimes]
```

Comment: Provide a text data sample instead of screenshots.  Answerers would like to cut-n-paste the test data.  Provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problems you are having. You have input and output state, but not what's wrong with your code.  What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure when you want to restart.
From what I understand you restart an hour if:

a) in prod date col last digit changes
b) when in pl seq first letter changes

What if we reach 24h and the (a or b) is False? Do we continue with 24h until we a or b is True?

Anyway you can add more conditions, I don't know if it is the most effective way but it works. Before doing it you have to create a column:

df['hours'] = 8, so it's a column with all rows = 8
and df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(filename))

```
prev_row = None
for index,row in df.iterrows():

    if prev_row is not None:

        if (row['pl'][0] == prev_row['pl'][0]) and (str(row['date'])[-2:] == str(prev_row['date'])[-2:]) :
            row['hours'] = prev_row['hours'] + 1
            print(row)
        else:
            row['hours'] = 8  
    df.iloc[index] = row     
    prev_row = row
```

Comment: Here is a link to the current state of my CSV file and the Goal

[link] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L7YQxyN9d-TKmEzHJUBMN3SXJxSnNgRJx3xISCE_v50/edit?usp=sharing)